# Difference in regex between Python and Rubular?

Tags: python, regex, rubular

In Rubular, I have created a regular expression:

```
(Prerequisite|Recommended): (\w|-| )*
```

It matches the bolded:

> **Recommended: good comfort level with computers and some of the arts.**
>
> Summer. 2 credits. **Prerequisite:
>   pre-freshman standing or permission of
>   instructor. Credit may not be applied
>   toward engineering degree.** S-U
>   grades only.

Here is a use of the regex in Python:

```
note_re = re.compile(r'(Prerequisite|Recommended): (\w|-| )*', re.IGNORECASE)

def prereqs_of_note(note):
    match = note_re.match(note)
    if not match:
        return None
    return match.group(0)
```

Unfortunately, the code returns `None` instead of a match:

```
>>> import prereqs

>>> result  = prereqs.prereqs_of_note("Summer. 2 credits. Prerequisite: pre-fres
hman standing or permission of instructor. Credit may not be applied toward engi
neering degree. S-U grades only.")

>>> print result
None
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** Do I need `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`?

Comment: http://pythex.org/ says that regular expression matches that string even using Python's engine, so the problem is with how you're using the regex (I don't know Python)

Comment: Also, personally I'd update your regex to `(Prerequisite|Recommended): ([\w -]*)` so you can better capture the rest of the match. (See http://rubular.com/r/5v7u66vc1M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `re.search()` because it scans the string. You don't want `re.match()` because it tries to apply the pattern at the start of the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Summer. 2 credits. Prerequisite: pre-freshman standing or permission of instructor. Credit may not be applied toward engineering degree. S-U grades only."""
>>> note_re = re.compile(r'(Prerequisite|Recommended): ([\w -]*)', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> note_re.search(s).groups()
('Prerequisite', 'pre-freshman standing or permission of instructor')
```

Also, if you want to match past the first period following the word "instructor" you're going to have to add a literal '.' into your pattern:

```
>>> re.search(r'(Prerequisite|Recommended): ([\w -\.]*)', s, re.IGNORECASE).groups()
('Prerequisite', 'pre-freshman standing or permission of instructor. Credit may not be applied toward engineering degree. S-U grades only.')
```

I would suggest you make your pattern greedier and match on the rest of the line, unless that's not really what you want, although it seems like you do.

```
>>> re.search(r'(Prerequisite|Recommended): (.*)', s, re.IGNORECASE).groups()
('Prerequisite', 'pre-freshman standing or permission of instructor. Credit may not be applied toward engineering degree. S-U grades only.')
```

The previous pattern with the addition of literal '.', returns the same as `.*` for this example.

Comment: ...or maybe `(.*?\.)` to match only up to the first period.